# How to select a class within a paragraph using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape just a certain class from a paragraph. I am using: `paragraph = soup.select('p', {'class' : icon-star'})`Is this the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find all related `p` elements by `class`:

```
ps = soup.find_all('p', class_='icon-star')
# then do something for ps
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("https://hassan-theitguy.github.io/")

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'siimple-link'}):
    print(a.get('href'))
```

Comment: @Susan I modified my answer to show complete code which I tested.